# Example of superreflexive space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Right now I'm studying the concept of superreflexivity and I would like to have a "basic" example of a superreflexive Banach space. A first and immediate example is finite dimensional spaces, but I would like to have one of an infinite dimensional Banach space.

I'd really appreciate your help. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Did you consult the [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Super-reflexive_space) page?

Comment: I read that, but I didn't notice that it is said that every X finitely representable in $\ell^2$ is a Hilbert space. This is implies that $\ell^2$ is superreflexive, right? Do you have a reference where I can find the demonstration of this fact?

Comment: No. But it does not seem that showing the parallelogram law must hold would be difficult.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It was proven by Enflo in 1970s that a Banach space $X$ is superreflexive iff $X$ admits an equivalent uniformly convex norm. This characterization provides many examples of superreflexive Banach spaces, e.g. $\ell^p$ for $1<p<\infty$. Another characterization is: $X$ is superreflexive iff ultraproducts of $X$ are reflexive.